# Which ports must firewall and VPN connection allow to use Memgraph Lab?

Tags: memgraphdb

I've downloaded Memgraph Lab desktop application and I want to connect to server that is at my university. So far I was connecting using SHH to get to mgconsole.

Now I would like to use Memgrpah Lab so that I can create images of graphs. I can see that Memgraph uses different ports 3000, 7444, 7687. Which of this ports must be accessible over VPN for me in order to connect from my home computer to server at university?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memgraph uses these three ports by default:

- `3000` - used by Memgraph Lab
- `7444` - used for accessing logs from Memgraph inside Memgraph Lab
- `7687` - used for communication with Memgraph via Bolt protocol

You can check the Memgraph configuration file with command `SHOW CONFIG;` to see if communication via Bolt is configured on a different port.